# JWT token authentication in .net core api with out passing the user credentials

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-apicontroller

I have used the following code to generate the token with valid audience .Burt I'm not getting the token generated when I tested in Postman. My intention is want to consume this API in another .Net core API .But no token is generating
start up code

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                List<string> validAudienceList = new List<string>();
                validAudienceList.Add("https://localhost:12345/");
                services.AddControllers();
                services.AddSwaggerGen();            
                services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
                {
                    c.SwaggerDoc("V1", new OpenApiInfo
                    {
                        Version="v1",
                        Title="Server Auth API V1",
                        Description= "List of Server Auth API"
                    });
                    var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                    var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
                    c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
                    c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                    {
                        Description="Input the jwt token as : Bearer {token}\"",
                        Name= "Authorization",
                        In=ParameterLocation.Header,
                        Scheme = "bearer", // must be lower case
                        BearerFormat = "JWT"
                        //Type=SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
                    });
                    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                    {
                        {
                            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                            {
                                Reference=new OpenApiReference
                                {
                                    Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                    Id="Bearer"
                                }
                            },new string[]{}                                                                                        
                        }
                    });
                });
                services.ConfigureSwaggerGen(options =>
                {
                    options.CustomSchemaIds(type => type.ToString());
                });
                services.AddCors(c =>
                {
                    c.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", options => options.AllowAnyOrigin());
                    c.AddPolicy("AllowHeader", options => options.AllowAnyHeader());
                    c.AddPolicy("AllowMethod", options => options.AllowAnyMethod());
                });
                JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
                services.AddAuthentication(x =>
                {
                    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddJwtBearer(y =>
                {
                    y.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    y.Authority = "https://localhost:12345/";
                    //y.SaveToken = true;
                    y.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        //ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        //IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuer = false, // set true when you have valid audience urls 
                        ValidateAudience = true, // set valid urls 
                        ValidAudiences = validAudienceList
                    };
                });
                services.AddMvc().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
                services.AddSession();
                //services.AddTransient<WeatherForecast>();
    
            }
    
            // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.

            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
            {
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                }
                else
                {
                    app.UseHsts();
                }
                app.UseSession();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
                {
                    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/V1/swagger.json", "Server Auth API V1");
                    // c.RoutePrefix = "swagger";
                    //c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
                });
                app.UseCors(options =>
                {
                    options.AllowAnyOrigin();
                    options.AllowAnyHeader();
                    options.AllowAnyMethod();
                });
                app.UseRouting();
                app.UseHttpsRedirection();
                app.UseAuthentication();
                app.UseAuthorization();
                app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapControllers();
                });
            }
```

Here I have added the controller code .

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]                [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes=JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]

```
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
                {
                    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
                    {
                        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
                    };
            
                    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;
            
                    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
                    {
                        _logger = logger;
                    }
            
                    [HttpGet]
                    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> GetWeatherReport()
                    {
                        var rng = new Random();
                        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
                        {
                            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
                        })
                        .ToArray();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: How did  you generate your access token? Follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-acquire-token?tabs=aspnetcore) which is similar with the scenario?  And can [this case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/378374/is-there-a-light-jwt-token-in-aspnet-core-web-api.html) help you?

Comment: Thanks for the response ! This example is asking for user credentials. But in my case I want to generate a token with out credentials .I want to generate only for valid audience.

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir and I failed to find any other solution on your requirement, sorry  for disturbing you : (

Comment: Not at all a problem ,I appreciate for your time. Thanks !